# Parse date from text file and extract lines where the date is greater than X

Tags: powershell

I have a client that uses third-party software to store confidential medical information. We now need to find out which users have opened a particular record in the database. I have been in touch with the vendor, and the only way they log it is in a text file on each individual computer(Apparently). I need to parse this text file from each computer to pull out the information I need. Here is an anonymous sample of the information in the text file - I have added spaces between each line for readability.

**Log in.|10/03/2012|01:12:45|Dr John Smith|3|FS01|Windows 7 Domain Controller with Terminal Services Service Pack 1 (6.1 Build 7601)|3.12.1**

**Progress Note - New record opened|10/03/2012|01:13:33|Dr John Smith|666241|8463|Richard Test^05/09/1956|.F.|.T.|1|FS01**

**Progress Note - Discarded by user|10/03/2012|01:14:29|Dr John Smith|666241|8463|Richard Test|.F.|.T.|FS01**

I can easily pull out any line with the record name in question i.e. "Richard test", but these logs go all the way back to 2012. Does anyone have any idea how I can parse the date from each line so that I can pull anything after 01/01/2016 for example?

```
import-module activedirectory
$computers = "FS01"#get-adcomputer -filter * | Select-object -ExpandProperty Name

foreach($computer in $computers){

$path = "\\$computer\C$\Users\Public\Documents\HCN\MD\MDTrace.LOG"
If(Test-Connection -ComputerName $computer -Count 1 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue){
If(Test-Path $Path){
Get-Content -Path $path | foreach { if($_ -match "Thomas Hogan"){Write-Output "$computer -- $_"} }
}
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found after trial and error I can do it with split in this case, as they are always separated by |

```
$computers = "NB04TMPL" #Get-Content D:\computers.txt | Sort-Object
$date = "21/01/2013"
$name = "Richard Test"
foreach ($computer in $computers)
{
    $path = "C:\temp\MDTrace.LOG"
    If (Test-Connection -ComputerName $computer -Count 1 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue)
    {
        If (Test-Path $Path)
        {
            Get-Content -Path $path | foreach {
                $str = ($_ -split '\|')
                if ($str[1] -gt $date)
                {
                    if ($str[6] -match $name)
                    {
                        Write-Output $_
                    }
                }
            }   
        }   
    }
}
```

Keen to hear any thoughts. I'm not sure how this stacks up against RegEx. I imagine RegEx would let me get a lot more flexibility with less If's

Answer (score 1):

Use a regular expression to extract the date, something like:

```
$cutoff = Get-Date -Year 2013 -Month 1 -Day 1
Get-Content .\log.txt | ? {
    $g = [regex]::Match($_, '(\d\d)/(\d\d)/(\d\d\d\d)').Groups
    (Get-Date -Year $g[3].Value -Month $g[2].Value -Day $g[1].Value) -gt $cutoff 
} | Out-File filtered_log.txt
```

If the files are large then this approach might be faster:

```
$cutoff = Get-Date -Year 2013 -Month 1 -Day 1
Get-Content .\log.txt -ReadCount 1 | % {
    $_ | ? {
        $g = [regex]::Match($_, '(\d\d)/(\d\d)/(\d\d\d\d)').Groups

        (Get-Date -Year $g[3].Value -Month $g[2].Value -Day $g[1].Value) -gt $cutoff 
    } | Out-File filtered_log.txt -Append
}
```

Comment: Thanks Dave. I need to look into Regex more closely. It seems a difficult thing to get the hang of